# What is the upload destination of file transfer activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In transfer activity page, there is source file setting, but don't have destination define setting.

Where would the file to be uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Upload File Transfers, the file gets uploaded to the File Location you select from the "Safehouse". If you choose to Download, the File is downloaded from the File Location you choose to the "Safehouse". Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

file will be uploaded to the FTP server you have set for the marketing cloud.